# Using URL Rewrite Rules for Dynamic and Pretty URLs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a page slugged `book-store`. I want this page to have different sections, namely: `category` and `book`. I'd like to use rewrite rules to achieve pretty urls that match the following example routes:

```
example.com/book-store/category/{category_name}
example.com/book-store/book/{book_id}
```

I've tried the following but I reckon I'm missing something important:

`functions.php`:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_state_var', 0, 1);
function add_state_var($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'category_name';
    $vars[] = 'book_id';
    return $vars;
}
```

`page-book-store.php`:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^book-store/category/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=page&name=book-store&book-category=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^book-store/book/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=page&name=book-store&book-id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

I then went into `/wp-admin` and clicked save in permalink settings

whenever I hit the urls `example.com/book-store/category/fiction` or `example.com/book-store/book/123` i get a 404

I'm using apache2.4 and mysql. The mod-rewrite module is enabled in apache.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: several questions: `book-store` is just a page? what contains `sections, namely: category and book`( page, post, cpt, category ) ?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, `book-store` is just a page. The sections `category` and `book` are just parameters I would use on the 'book-store' page to show appropriate books, they are not posts, pages, or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand right:

- you have page `example.com/book-store/`
- you want to create urls like:

  ```
  example.com/book-store/category/{category_name}
  example.com/book-store/book/{book_id}
  ```

  where the `{category_name}` and `{book_id}` are [`query vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)

The code you added into `page-book-store.php` file will not work, just because the url was queried before your code. Also, the filter `add_filter('query_vars', 'add_state_var', 0, 1);` will not work, too. The priority of this filter is 10, but you used 0.

To achieve your goal add this code into your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('init', 'ww_rewrite_book_store');
function ww_rewrite_book_store(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%book_id%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^(book-store)/book/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&book_id=$matches[2]', 'top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%category_name%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^(book-store)/category/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

After go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and just click to <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> button.

First, we used [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) to establish the query vars. And used [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to make it work right.

For example, if your url will be `example.com/book-store/category/some_category`, you can use query vars( get `{some_category}` ) in the `page-book-store.php` file like:

```
echo get_query_var('category_name');
```